# Padding in Strings in swing textarea / creating a table

Tags: java, string, swing, format, textarea

I would like to create a table in my swing textarea output in Java. The columns contain filenames, a boolean and some numbers. The width of the filename differs in every row.

I tried to use String.format() like this:

```
String.format("|%1$-120s|%2$-40s|%3$-40s|", filename, true/false, numbers_as_string);
```

Nevertheless, the size of the columns are not equally 120. After that I tried to resize the filename Strings with a short function:

```
    private String StringOutput(String inputString, int length) {       
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
           sb.append(' ');
        }
        return inputString + sb.substring(inputString.length()) ;
    }
```

When I print the size of the Strings, it is 120 for every returned filename. But the size of the columns in the textarea is different again and it does not look like a table.

Do you have any suggestions for this?

Comment: You probably want to use a monospaced font (Font.MONOSPACED)

Comment: Why not use a [JTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: The textarea represents log outputs and results in my frame. I am not allowed to use a additional JTable.